# error when getting Facebook user data by asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

> I had this error when getting facebook user details .
>
> {    "error": {
>         "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 101    } }

```
public partial class DefaultPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,email",            
        Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]); 
        FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "111111111111111";
        FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


            if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('User has denied access.')", true);
                return;
            }

            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
                FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
                faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);
                pnlFaceBookUser.Visible = true;
                //lblId.Text = faceBookUser.Id;
                //lblUserName.Text = faceBookUser.UserName;
                lblName.Text = faceBookUser.Name;
                //lblEmail.Text = faceBookUser.Email;
                ProfileImage.ImageUrl = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
                //btnLogin.Enabled = false;
          }
        }
    }

public class FaceBookUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: cannot get what you need :( can you make sentences shorter ? and put a clear question ? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had this error when getting facebook user details .
>
> { "error": { "message": "Missing client_id parameter.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 101 } }

Means you got a problem with yours :

```
FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "111111111111111";
FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

It should be fit with your facebook app as it says at [facebook docutmention](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#creating)

Also there is an excelent [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333706/Classic-ASP-and-Facebook-Graph-API)

Hope that's help.